# Grails 3.0 propertyInstanceMap for a batch insert

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Previously I was using the session cleanup [trick](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql) to insert a large number of records i.e.

```
def propertyInstanceMap = DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP

def cleanUpGorm() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
    propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
}
```

I can't find the PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP on the DomainClassGrailsPlugin in Grails 3.0 and consequently the app is dying during the import. Can anyone tell me where this property resides in 3.0? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it seems that in Grails 3, you do not need to clear anymore the property instance map.

Did you notice any performance issue by deleting the line where you clear the propertyInstanceMap? I did, and I did not encounter any performance regression yet.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

`DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP.get().clear()`

I haven't used Grails 3.0, but this should work.

Comment: @Toby I found it at grails-plugin-domain-class/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/domain/DomainClassGrailsPlugin.groovy in grails core 3.0. So you could try importing it using `org.grails.plugins.domain.DomainClassGrailsPlugin`

Comment: I found the class, its the property on the class that I now can't find in 3.0 i.e. PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP. I'm not sure if Grails 3.0 uses a different validation mechanism now

Comment: hi...i have a same problem? have you found it?